# PHP preg_match, Finding a package name from Android URL address

Tags: php

I need to get Android package name from the URL address.

Here is what I have done.

```
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamevil.projectn.global&feature=featured-apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMywiY29tLmdhbWV2aWwucHJvamVjdG4uZ2xvYmFsIl0.';
        preg_match("~id=(\d+)~", $url, $matches);
        $package_name = $matches[1];

        echo $package_name;
```

Package name should be "com.gamevil.projectn.global"

However, my code is not working.

Is there something that I  miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function

```
<?php
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamevil.projectn.global&feature=featured-apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMywiY29tLmdhbWV2aWwucHJvamVjdG4uZ2xvYmFsIl0.';
$arr =parse_url($url);
$new = explode("&",$arr['query']);
$new1 = explode("=",$new[0]);
echo($new1[1] );
```

output

```
com.gamevil.projectn.global
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamevil.projectn.global&feature=featured-apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMywiY29tLmdhbWV2aWwucHJvamVjdG4uZ2xvYmFsIl0.';
    preg_match("/id=(.*?)&/", $url, $matches);
    $package_name = $matches[1];

    echo $package_name;
```

`preg_match` will no find everything between `id=` and `&`.

But a better solution is to use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to parse the url and this function will return the components of the url.